# Exclude the Predefined keywords from Word (alphanums+'_.') in pyparsing python

Tags: pyparsing, predefined-variables

```
selectStmt=(select +
        ('*' |delimitedList(functionbody|column)).setResultsName("Columns") + Optional((_as+table.setResultsName("Aliases"))|table.setResultsName("**Aliases1**"),'')+
        Optional(_into+('*' |columns).setResultsName("Columns"),'')+
        _from +
        table.setResultsName("Tables",listAllMatches=True)+Optional((_as+table.setResultsName("Aliases"))|table.setResultsName(**Aliases2**),'')+
        Optional(where + Group(whereExpr), '').setResultsName("where") +
        Each([Optional(groupby + columns("groupby")+Optional(_asc|_desc,''),'').setDebug(False),
            Optional(orderby + columns("orderby"),'').setDebug(False),Optional(_limit+columnVal,'')
            ])).setResultsName("Select",listAllMatches=True)+Optional((_union_all|_union)+selectStmt,'').setResultsName("Union")
```

so if i am matching query like

```
select count(id) sellercount
            into v_photocount
            from carphotos photos
            where inquiryid = v_inquiryid
                and isdealer = (
                                case 
                                when v_sellertype = 1  then 1
                                                      else 0
                                end
                               )
                and isactive = 1
                and isapproved = 1;
```

Then sellercount is matching with _into and photos with where.
How can I avoid This